# EWS $mail.body.text.toString() - Null value

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to read e-mail bodies with EWS and Powershell 3.0. Everything is working fine, however, when the body contains no tekst I get a You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. Is there any way I can check if the mail body is empty?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Any reason why you call .ToString() on property, that is already a string...? That's a source of your issue (calling method may cause error, accessing property usually won't), so if there is no value added in .ToString() - maybe it would be wise to stick to `$mail.Body.Text` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the text property is equal to null, or test the length of the mail text.